# Lookup Equivalent - Display Results in HTML table

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow

I currently have a flow that scrapes bookings made (from MS Bookings) into an Outlook Calendar and prepares a HTML table that I can then email to people or use in different reports.

Outlook previously tagged the person in the meeting as 'Category' but have since removed this. I can get the email address of the person who is the 'requiredAttendees', and then I have a SharePoint list to compare to.

What I'd like to do, is be able to do a simple lookup requiredAttendees > SharePoint List and return Interviewer for each record.

I've done all the Get Items and such which seems to work no problem. I just need some assistance in putting the last bits together.

[image: First part of flow collecting bookings]

[image: Composing table, Interviewer now picking up blanks because it doesnt recognise 'categories']